# How to add my custom BNB Token on my shopify or woo-commerce store

Tags: web3js, binance

I have created my own custom BEP20 token on Binance smart chain and want to add it as a payment method on my Woo-commerce or shopify store. Actually my store is running on shopify and it would be good if there is a way to add my token as a payment method on it. However if it is not possible on shopify i can migrate to woo-commerce. But i still need to know how to add my token as a payment method on a woo-commerce store, So that my customer who have my token can use these tokens to buy stuff on my store. I can write code so if there is an easy way with coding it is perfect too.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
https://mycryptocheckout.com

It charges a yearly fee to have your custom token added to their list of accepted tokens that can be used as a payment method. I haven't tried it but, I am going to.

Otherwise, I haven't found an exact answer to your question.